# confused about definition of "equalizer" in category theory

Tags: category-theory

An equalizer in a category C is a limit of a functor from I with two objects x,y, and two non-identity morphisms f and g.  I was wondering if the two objects, x, y could be map to the the same object in C, and the two non-identity morphisms f, and g, could be map to the same morphism in C.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, they can can be any objects and any morphisms. There isn't even a requirement that the maps are not identity. It is worth trying to figure out what the equalizer is in some simple cases. For example, in the category of abelian groups, the equalizer is the kernel of the difference of the two maps.

Comment: Yes, they could. As usual in mathematics, having two variables $x$ and $y$ doesn't exclude the possibility $x = y$.

Comment: Indeed, it is sometimes worth thinking of equalizers as a generalization of the idea of "kernel" from group theory to categories. where "kernel" doesn't quite make sense.